# Retrieving a value from a database and display in tooltip

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a tooltip using javascript and have an html page using that tooltip.
Here is my tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Tooltips
$(".tip_trigger").hover(function (e) {
    tip = $(this).find('.tip');
    var tipText = $(e.target).attr('ti');
    tip.html(tipText);
    tip.show(); //Show tooltip
}, function () {
    tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip        
}).mousemove(function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
    var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
    var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

    //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
    var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
    //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
    var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

    if (tipVisX < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
        mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
    } if (tipVisY < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
        mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
    }
    tip.css({ top: mousey, left: mousex });
});
});
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1><span>Simple Example</span></h1>
<map name="Koala" class="tip_trigger">
<area ti="This is the left eye" shape="rect" coords="373,365,404,402" href="#" />
<area ti="Right Eye" shape="rect" coords="641,405,681,448" href="#" />

    <div class="tip"></div>
```

I want the database value to display where "ti" is... ex. ti="database value"
How can this be done? I will be using MySQL along with php. All help I will be very grateful for.

Comment: what is your server side scripting engine ?

Comment: Hello, I was thinking of using php since it goes so well with MySQL

Comment: and what you tried with php ?

Comment: Well, I know how to retrieve values from a database with php, I guess to be more precise, I am not sure how or where i would put the php code so that I can retrieve database values to be used in my html.  Also I am unsure how i would put the php code INTO the html area tags?  Thank you for your response, let me know if what i just said is useless and i will try to re word it :)

Comment: you need a way to tell server about which row you  clicked and show answer in tooltip ?

Comment: For example: if i hovered over the hotspot <area ti="This is the left eye" shape="rect" coords="373,365,404,402" href="#" /> I want a database value to display in the tooltip instead of "This is the left eye".

Comment: in your data print loop type `<area ti="<?php echo $row->ti; ?>" shape="rect" coords="373,365,404,402" href="#" />` I think your problem is that you want to type more questions, than read php documetnation.

Comment: [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: I have searched and searched, and have tried numerous times before coming here because I knew it would be a difficult question to answer. I will read the php docs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a help table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `help` (
  `helpID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `helpText` text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `helpID` (`helpID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For a generic tooltip, on the page where you want the help tip, put this html:

```
<span id="productSKUHelp" class="helpTip questionMark"></span>
```

Since you want the tooltip to appear when your cursor is in a certain spot, you should be able to use your mousemove function and call showTip.

Add the following JQuery:

```
  function showTip(thisTip){
    var postdata = {
      helpTip: thisTip.attr('id')
    };
    $.ajax({
             type    : "post",
             url     : "/getHelpRPC.php",
             dataType: "html",
             data    : postdata,
             success : function(data){
               if(data.length > 0){
                 var origContent = thisTip.html();
                 thisTip.removeClass("questionMark").addClass('helpTipBox');
                 thisTip.html(data);

               }else{
                 $('#helpTipBox').html("error");
               }
             },
             error   : function(xhr, textStatus, error){
               console.log(xhr.statusText);
               console.log(textStatus);
               console.log(error);
             }
           });

  }

  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.helpTip', function(){
    var thisTip = $(this);
    helpTipTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                                showTip(thisTip);
                              },
                              1000);
  })
  $(document).on('click', '.helpTip', function(){
    showTip($(this));
  })
  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.helpTip', function(){
    clearTimeout(helpTipTimer);
    $(this).html('').removeClass('helpTipBox').addClass('questionMark');
  });
```

Add the following CSS:

```
.helpTip{
  padding-left:3px;
  z-index:900;
}

.questionMark:after{
  color:maroon;
  cursor:pointer;
  content:"?";
  top:2px;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 3px;
}

.helpTipBox{
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#97abcc;
  position:absolute;
  curson:text;
}
```

Create the getHelpRPC.php RPC:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB);

if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed: %s %s %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit();
}

$helpID = $_POST['helpTip'];
if($helpID != ""){
    $querystr = "SELECT helpText FROM help WHERE helpID ='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($helpID) . "'";
    $res = $mysqli->query($querystr);
    $rowCount = $res->num_rows;
    if($rowCount > 0){
        $row = $res->fetch_object();
        echo $row->helpText;
    } else {
        echo "error selecting help.";
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is create a unique id in the span and add the corresponding record to the table.